# asp.net response.write with bootbox.alert

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, asp.net

Response.Write("alert(Username or password invalid);");

from codebehind to warn user. But i wanna show it more goodlooking. I saw bootbox and added to library

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootbox.min.js"></script>
```

But when i enter wrong info it doesnt make any alert. Can you tell me where i am making this wrong please. Thank You

This code i am using; (in button click, after it goes 'else')

```
  else
   {
 Response.Write("<script type=text/javascript>bootbox.alert(Username or password invalid);</script>");
   }
```

Comment: You probably need to fix quotes. And make use of `ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript`

Comment: It's hard to say with the few code you're showing us, but most probably you included bootbox at the end of your page render (just before the end of your body) as it is a good practice, while your codebehind would most probably call the method before the library is even included. Try including the library in the `<head>` of your document instead. P.S : you can drop the `type` attribute on your `script` tag.

Comment: You should NEVER use response.write to output JavaScript.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not quoting the string in JavaScript.  Take a look at what you're emitting to the page:

```
Response.Write("<script type=text/javascript>bootbox.alert(Username or password invalid);</script>");
```

This will result in:

```
<script type=text/javascript>bootbox.alert(Username or password invalid);</script>
```

The browser will *probably* correct the unquoted `type` attribute for you, but JavaScript won't correct the unquoted string for you.  Your JavaScript console is probably showing an error that `Username` isn't defined or something of that nature.

So first you'll need to properly quote the strings:

```
Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">bootbox.alert('Username or password invalid');</script>");
```

Now, even aside from that, you *really* shouldn't use `Response.Write()` to emit values to the page.  It gives you no control over *where* on the page things are placed, and that can be important.  Take a look at [`RegisterStartupScript`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.clientscriptmanager.registerstartupscript%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as an alternative.  This would include the client-side code in a more appropriate location in the page.

Comment: thanks you for reply i tried this Response.Write("<script type=\"text/javascript\">bootbox.alert('Username or password invalid');</script>"); but still same.